# What is the maximum paragon level?

Tags: diablo-iii

In the `Profile` window accessible in the hero selection screen under the `Heroes` tab, there is a progress bar that tells you what paragon level you have and gives you a 'percentage completed' indicator for the next paragon level.

[image: example of total paragon progress bar]

There is no indication for when I will reach max paragon level. Does anyone know what the max paragon level is?

<s>The example that I have provided indicates that paragon level 123 is approximately 4% of the way to completion (1/25th). Some simple math (123*25) will give an estimate completion around level 3000. Can anyone confirm whether or not that is the maximum paragon level?</s>[***edit:*** The percentage value indicates progress through the current paragon level and is not an indication of a maximum paragon level.]

---

Bonus points if you can provide some form of graph indicating the XP required per paragon level and what its upward trend looks like from level 0 through to whatever the cap may be.

Comment: The completion bar and percentage shows how much % of paragon experience you have for current level.

Comment: A streamer recentlty reached Para 1000 and is now 1003 so I assume you an at least go up to 9999 but thats just a guess

Comment: @Chippies Ah, did not realize that. Looking again (with a different amount of xp), it becomes rather obvious. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [wiki](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Paragon) states that since the release of Reaper of Souls (Paragon 2.0):

> There is no cap on Paragon levels. Players can now earn as many Paragon levels as they please. All that needs to be done is to simply fight monsters and complete quests with a hero already at lv. 60 or 70, depending upon the player's (lack of, if appropriate) access to Reaper of Souls.

[This chart](http://www.diablofans.com/news/47858-paragon-exp-chart-levels-1-2000-diablofans) (provided by Arperum) shows a current XP requirement per level, up to 2000. (I would post it here but it would be way too huge)

As for a fancy pie chart, I can only provide (an old model) up to 100, as the 2.0 version suggests there is no level cap.

[image]

Comment: Any explanation of the percentage indicator paired with the paragon level in the Hero Profile menu?

Comment: This pie chart is also from the old paragon version, and is completely incorrect for the new version. The xp required for getting new paragon levels has been significantly reduced.

Comment: @Lemmings19 As Chippies suggested above, the percentage is the completion of the current Paragon level.

Comment: @Arperum That is true, and I didn't intend for it to represent the current build. If you have a different source showing a difference in the levels (up to 100) go for it :)

Comment: [here you go, no fancy pie chart though](http://www.diablofans.com/news/47858-paragon-exp-chart-levels-1-2000-diablofans), you can make one yourself in any chartmaking program.

Comment: This answer is incorrect, the max is indeed 10,000 as the down-voted answers state. It can be tested by modding the game, it will not go past 10,000. That being said it's pretty much impossible to get to that point without cheating.

Comment: @Spencer if you have proof of this, by all means please do provide it. At the time of posting, this answer was the best you were going to get, as there was *no proof whatsoever* at the time.

Comment: Unfortunately Blizzard never officially confirmed it, only that those who have a modded/exploit versions of the game will show that you can't go past 10,000 paragon (*I don't own a modded version*). I would recommend using the quote directly from the [patch notes](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/game/patch-notes/2-0-1) rather than a wiki which may not be reliable. That being said having *"no cap"* is impossible, generally that claim is made when the cap too high to legitimately achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Technically because of the limitation of computers, there is always a maximum value of anything. That number may be astronomically huge, but it still exists.

In this case, I would guess they're storing the value in game as a `signed 32 bit integer`. In which case the max paragon level would be `2,147,483,647`. Assuming someone managed to reach this level and then leveled passed that level, they would then be paragon level `-2,147,483,648` because the maximum value will have been reached and it will then reset back to the lowest value.

Of course the value could also be an `unsigned 32 bit integer` where the max would be `4,294,967,295` and it would then reset to `0` after that value was reached. It could also be a `64 bit` value where `9,223,372,036,854,775,807` was the max and `-9,223,372,036,854,775,808` was the minimum if it was `signed` and `18,446,744,073,709,551,615` was the max and `0` was the min if it was `unsigned`.

It could also be integers of other bit sizes such as 16 bit, or 128 bit. The only thing we know for sure is that it is not an 8 bit value since people have gone far beyond the max value of an 8 bit value (255 if unsigned).

Depending on how they coded the game, it may not allow you to go beyond the max value, it might reset to 0 or really low negative value, or it may even crash your game due to an uncaught exception.

Anyways, there is always technically a limit. The limit is probably nothing anyone could reach in a thousand life times without hacking, but there is a limit.

Comment: Though the highest storable value wouldn't be reached for paragon- the required experience would overflow first.

Comment: Good point Studoku.

Comment: +1 for overflows and some explanation. Although, as Studoku mentioned, after paragon level *gazillion* you will either end up with all levels being equally long, either it will overflow and next levels will become tremendously short

Answer (score 0):

It is infact the last paragon level is 10,000

Comment: This conflicts with the citations in the accepted answer; do you have data to back up your answer?

Answer (score -1):

My character is at level 70 and my paragon is up in the 8500 Mark I played with someone online and talked to him and said it capped out at 10,000 that was after the upgrade to 2.0.1 or something like that.

Comment: Hello Nick. If you're wondering why people downvoted your answer, it is because the community at Stack Exchange (this site) expects answers to be definitive. This would usually require some certainty or a cited source to back up your claim. Unfortunately, hearing another guy say something online doesn't provide much evidence for an answer.